# How to create modules for android qpython

Tags: android, import, qpython

As a newbie to qpython (and python) I am trying to develop a library of useful functions for myself.  I gather that I should be able to save a file of those functions somewhere (with a .py extention) and then import them into a console session. Under qpython I see two tabs: console and editor. If I create a file under editor and save it (e.g., to mylib.py) and then try to import it into a console session, with the line:   `"import mylib"`
I get the error:
`ImportError: No module named mylib`
I assume that I have saved the module in the wrong director.  Where should I save it?  Are my assumptions correct?  Is there a document that explains all of this that I should read?

Thanks for any help you can give.